# Can I report on versions being deployed in POM files in multiple repositories?

Tags: java, git, maven

I have a number of repositories each with their own POM files.

These POM files contain the versions of pieces of third party software that are being deployed e.g. Tomcat, JRE, Angular etc...

Is there any way in which I can easily report on all components and or software being deployed across multiple repositories and POM files easily and quickly so that I can see what is being deployed where without manually opening each POM file one by one?

Reason behind this is so that I can quickly check if any vulnerable versions of software are being deployed when a vulnerability is identified.